# Rust method handling number overflows and signed/unsigned fields with generics

Tags: generics, rust

I am currently dealing with a question on Rust, hope this is not a too stupid question.
The problem I am trying to solve is the following:

I want to have a `struct` witch two numeric fields, `x` and `y`. These numeric fields can be either signed or unsigned. These fields should only be numeric, float or int, but can be signed or unsigned.

The `struct` has one method called `offset`, which allows to increase or decrease the values of the fields.
However, the behaviour of the `offset` method has to change depending on if the fields of the `struct` are signed or unsigned, because if the fields are unsigned they can never be negative.
This problem is illustrated below:

```rust
use std::ops::AddAssign;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Coords<T: AddAssign> {
    x: T,
    y: T,
}

impl<T: AddAssign> Coords<T> {
    /// Allows to change the values of the fields
    fn offset(&mut self, dx: T, dy: T) {
        self.x += dx;
        self.y += dy;
    }
}

// This works well for signed number. The offset method works for signed integers.
let x: i8 = 0;
let y: i8 = 0;
let mut coords = Coords{ x, y };
coords.offset(-10, -10);
println!("{:?}", coords); // Coords { x: -10, y: -10 }

// However, this does not work if x and y were unsigned
let x: u8 = 0;
let y: u8 = 0;
let mut coords = Coords{ x, y };
// This does not compile.
// Should give the result as Coords { x: 0, y: 0 }
// coords.offset(-10, -10);
```

I am trying to write an implementation of the `offset` method as to handle the scenarios where the fields of `Coords` can be either float or int, signed or unsigned. What would be the cleanest and most idiomatic way of solving this?

I tried playing around with traits from the `num` crate, but no success so far. I think I could just write two structs, one for unsigned fields and another for signed fields, each of this with a different implementation of the `offset` method, but I am pretty sure that there is a more idiomatic solution for this in Rust.

Thank you :)

Comment: Firstly, specify your question. What if your struct has type `u64` but you add a `f64` in? What about `u8` but offset by `i32`?

Comment: But that is what I am trying to ask. At the end, I want to have an offset function that allows me to add or subtract values from my fields. But this should be able to handle various field types

Comment: The easiest way is to stick with the most general form of data you will deal with, i.e. `f64` in this case. The second best way is probably create an enum `Numeric` that has e.g. `Numeric::Uint(u64)` and `Numeric::Int(i64)` and `Numeric::Double(f64)`, then implement the arithmetic traits on it, essentially trying from u64 -> i64 -> f64 and see which one succeeds first.

Comment: I will try this, seems promising. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a trait to represent your number and the allowed operations on it.
Something like the following:

```
trait CoordType : Copy {
    type Signed;
    fn offset(self, d: Self::Signed) -> Self;
}
```

You could also add `AddAssign` and/or `SubAssign` as requirements for this trait, depending on the intended usage, but they are not needed for this simple example, because the `offset()` function takes care of everything.

The impls for `i8` and `u8` would be as follows:

```
impl CoordType for i8 {
    type Signed = i8;
    fn offset(self, d: Self::Signed) -> Self {
        self.saturating_add(d)
    }
}

impl CoordType for u8 {
    type Signed = i8;
    fn offset(self, d: Self::Signed) -> Self {
        if d >= 0 {
            self.saturating_add(d as u8)
        } else {
            self.saturating_sub(-d as u8)
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using `saturating_add/sub` instead of plain `+` and `-` to avoid panics on overflows. If you need that for `i16`, `u16`, `i32`, `u32`, etc. then a macro would help a lot.

The implementations for `f32` and `f64` should be also quite straightforward.

And then your `Coords` type is trivially implemented as:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Coords<T: CoordType> {
    x: T,
    y: T,
}

impl<T: CoordType> Coords<T> {
    fn offset(&mut self, dx: T::Signed, dy: T::Signed) {
        self.x = self.x.offset(dx);
        self.y = self.y.offset(dy);
    }
}
```

Here is a [link to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8c8a185d0b6a33a0e924414c2d8fa2f6) with that code.

Comment: This seems to be what I need. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @dkzed: Rust just stabilized [u8::saturating_add_signed](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.u8.html#method.saturating_add_signed) that could make your unsigned impls even simpler.